# How to grep between words in a log?

Tags: sed, grep, output

I have a txt file with lines like below.

Starting With:

```
 Parameters: {"raw_message"=>"MSH.......
```

Ending With:

```
</HL7Message>"}
```

I'm wanting to grep and output to a file the words between raw and transformed which appears halfway through each line.

The file appears like below

```
Parameters: {"raw_message"=>"MSH....... "transformed_data".....</HL7Message>"}

Parameters: {"raw_message"=>"MSH....... "transformed_data".....</HL7Message>"}

Parameters: {"raw_message"=>"MSH....... "transformed_data".....</HL7Message>"}

Parameters: {"raw_message"=>"MSH....... "transformed_data".....</HL7Message>"}
```

Best case scenario

The MSH following the >MSH begins the output but there are many MSH instances in each line. So i figured it could be logical to grep the between message and then rip the raw and transformed part out.

```
raw_message"=>"MSH......preceding words followed by transformed
```

Some possible words preceding transformed
    LAB\r", "transformed
    00355", "transformed

So I'd want

```
MSH....LAB\r
MSH....00355
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

I tried:

```
sed -n "/<raw>/,/<\/transformed>/p" HL7prod.txt > HL7prod2.txt
```

Example Line

```
 Parameters: {"raw_message"=>"MSH|^~\\&||CDFGTL|||20144543000||ATG^A05|TLGTADM.1.13773085|P|2.1\rEVN|A08|11111111111|||MDFGQ8833^HLPS^GEGES^^^^\rPID|1||K11111111|K1111111|HOLVBVFS^LGDSA^^^^||19GHYSSD|F|^^^^^||^^^^^^^^|||||||K01045435547691\rPV1|1|P|K.ER^^||||LKIJK^Liujn^Jeggrs^H^^^MD|||ER||||||N||ER|||||||||||||||||||||DFLHL|ABD DFIN|PRE|||111111111||||||||\rZCS||^^^^||||00355", "transformed_data"=>"<HL7Message><MSH><MSH.1>|</MSH.1><MSH.2>^~\\&amp;</MSH.2><MSH.3><MSH.3.1>CDFLH</MSH.3.1></MSH.3><MSH.4><MSH.4.1>COCTL</MSH.4.1></MSH.4><MSH.5/><MSH.6/><MSH.7><MSH.7.1>201506331000</MSH.7.1></MSH.7><MSH.8/><MSH.9><MSH.9.1>ADT</MSH.9.1><MSH.9.2>A08</MSH.9.2></MSH.9><MSH.10><MSH.10.1>TLGGBGM.1.13773076</MSH.10.1></MSH.10><MSH.11><MSH.11.1>P</MSH.11.1></MSH.11><MSH.12><MSH.12.1>2.1</MSH.12.1></MSH.12></MSH><EVN><EVN.1><EVN.1.1>A08</EVN.1.1></EVN.1><EVN.2><EVN.2.1>201506125500</EVN.2.1></EVN.2><EVN.3/><EVN.4/><EVN.5><EVN.5.1>MDHYQ6633</EVN.5.1><EVN.5.2>LUJKL</EVN.5.2><EVN.5.3>JYTEDFG</EVN.5.3><EVN.5.4/><EVN.5.5/><EVN.5.6/><EVN.5.7/></EVN.5></EVN><PID><PID.1><PID.1.1>1</PID.1.1></PID.1><PID.2/><PID.3><PID.3.1>K0567432372</PID.3.1></PID.3><PID.4><PID.4.1>K5894336</PID.4.1></PID.4><PID.5><PID.5.1>HOLDFGEER</PID.5.1><PID.5.2>AAAAS</PID.5.2><PID.5.3/><PID.5.4/><PID.5.5/><PID.5.6/></PID.5><PID.6/><PID.7><PID.7.1>1111111111</PID.7.1></PID.7><PID.8><PID.8.1>F</PID.8.1></PID.8><PID.9><PID.9.1/><PID.9.2/><PID.9.3/><PID.9.4/><PID.9.5/><PID.9.6/></PID.9><PID.10/><PID.11><PID.11.1/><PID.11.2/><PID.11.3/><PID.11.4/><PID.11.5/><PID.11.6/><PID.11.7/><PID.11.8/><PID.11.9/></PID.11><PID.12/><PID.13><PID.13.1/></PID.13><PID.14/><PID.15/><PID.16/><PID.17/><PID.18><PID.18.1>K0101333333333</PID.18.1></PID.18></PID><PV1><PV1.1><PV1.1.1>1</PV1.1.1></PV1.1><PV1.2><PV1.2.1>P</PV1.2.1></PV1.2><PV1.3><PV1.3.1>K.ER</PV1.3.1><PV1.3.2/><PV1.3.3/></PV1.3><PV1.4/><PV1.5/><PV1.6/><PV1.7><PV1.7.1>JTOLOKS</PV1.7.1><PV1.7.2>Ldasfs</PV1.7.2><PV1.7.3>Jtuygikd</PV1.7.3><PV1.7.4>H</PV1.7.4><PV1.7.5/><PV1.7.6/><PV1.7.7>MD</PV1.7.7></PV1.7><PV1.8/><PV1.9/><PV1.10><PV1.10.1>ER</PV1.10.1></PV1.10><PV1.11/><PV1.12/><PV1.13/><PV1.14/><PV1.15/><PV1.16><PV1.16.1>N</PV1.16.1></PV1.16><PV1.17/><PV1.18><PV1.18.1>ER</PV1.18.1></PV1.18><PV1.19/><PV1.20/><PV1.21/><PV1.22/><PV1.23/><PV1.24/><PV1.25/><PV1.26/><PV1.27/><PV1.28/><PV1.29/><PV1.30/><PV1.31/><PV1.32/><PV1.33/><PV1.34/><PV1.35/><PV1.36/><PV1.37/><PV1.38/><PV1.39><PV1.39.1>COTOLA</PV1.39.1></PV1.39><PV1.40><PV1.40.1>ABD XXXX</PV1.40.1></PV1.40><PV1.41><PV1.41.1>PRE</PV1.41.1></PV1.41><PV1.42/><PV1.43/><PV1.44><PV1.44.1>111111111</PV1.44.1></PV1.44><PV1.45/><PV1.46/><PV1.47/><PV1.48/><PV1.49/><PV1.50/><PV1.51/><PV1.52/></PV1><ZCS><ZCS.1/><ZCS.2><ZCS.2.1/><ZCS.2.2/><ZCS.2.3/><ZCS.2.4/><ZCS.2.5/></ZCS.2><ZCS.3/><ZCS.4/><ZCS.5/><ZCS.6><ZCS.6.1>111111</ZCS.6.1></ZCS.6></ZCS><GT1><GT1.6><GT1.6.1/></GT1.6></GT1><ZRF><ZRF.1><ZRF.1.1>COTYUL</ZRF.1.1></ZRF.1><ZRF.2><ZRF.2.1>CDFTL</ZRF.2.1><ZRF.2.2>K.ER</ZRF.2.2></ZRF.2></ZRF></HL7Message>"}
```

Would Want:

```
MSH|^~\\&||CDFGTL|||20144543000||ATG^A05|TLGTADM.1.13773085|P|2.1\rEVN|A08|11111111111|||MDFGQ8833^HLPS^GEGES^^^^\rPID|1||K11111111|K1111111|HOLVBVFS^LGDSA^^^^||19GHYSSD|F|^^^^^||^^^^^^^^|||||||K01045435547691\rPV1|1|P|K.ER^^||||LKIJK^Liujn^Jeggrs^H^^^MD|||ER||||||N||ER|||||||||||||||||||||DFLHL|ABD DFIN|PRE|||25679506645657||||||||\rZCS||^^^^||||00355
```

Comment: You should provide actual complete examples.

Comment: @jordanm Added an example after making it anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the text between your patterns on each line, do the following:

```
sed 's/.*raw\(.*\)transformed.*/\1/'
```

`\(.*\)` *remembers* the text that is output using `\1`.  Other stuff onthe line is not output.

Comment: I editied what you recommended a bit and it works great!                           sed 's/.*raw_message"=>"\(.*\)", "transformed.*/\1/' HL7prod.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you have a grep that supports PCREs, you can do

```
$ grep -oP 'Parameters: {"raw_message"=>"\K.+?(?=", "transformed_data")' file
```

Or, if your files are as you show, simplify to:

```
$ grep -oP '=>"\K.+?(?=",)' file
```

Alternatively, use `awk`, set the field separator to an `=>` or a `,` and print the second field (this also matches the `"`, pipe through `tr -d`"` to remove them):

```
$ awk -F'[,>]' '{print $2}' file
```

Or, you could just grep for the first quoted string starting with MSH:

```
$ grep -Po '"MSH.+?"' file
```

And, avoiding the quotes:

```
$ grep -Po '"\KMSH.*?(?=")' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes in your ***Example Line*** do seem to be fairly significant. If there is no chance of an escaped quote in that string, then all you have to do is:

```sh
cut -d\" -f4 <in >out
```

To get the fourth field on a line as separated by `"`double-quote delimiters.

If double-quotes might occur escaped in that string - such as by backslashes - then you could do:

```sh
sed 's/[^>]*."//;s/", ".*//'
```

...to get safely get only the field you want without skipping anything and without false positives. The above two substitutions should handle that pretty robustly if those are the only quote characters *(not counting backslashes)* which might be used, and given all of the `raw` bits start like `>` and that there is no `>` occurring anywhere before it.